# What's the best way for me to get unrestricted access to Brazil?

Tags: brazil, residency

I want to live in Brazil, permanently. I know about how to get investment visas or marriage visas and that kind of thing. But I was thinking maybe there was a cheaper or easier option. For example getting a passport from another country that has unrestricted access to Brazil. Any ideas?

Comment: fyi I am from the UK with a British passport

Comment: The best passport to get unrestricted access to Brazil is Brazilian.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Brazilian Nationality Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_nationality_law), the easiest way is to figure out how to live there for at least four years, learn Portuguese, and don't get (or already have) any criminal convictions. After that, you can apply for Brazilian citizenship and come and go as you please.

If you find a Brazilian partner and marry, or have a Brazilian child, then the time requirement is only one year.

Of course, the trick is to figure out how to live there. You will probably have to get a job in Brazil and an extendable work visa.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a citizen of the MERCOSUL or Portugal, you have special privileges. MERCOSUL citizens can work in Brazil and Portuguese citizens can request a "igualdade de direitos".

Citizens of other countries will have to get a work visa there are several of them. Generally speaking, to get a work visa you need to be hired and sponsored by a Brazilian company.

Here's a list of visas available:

VITEM I

Research, Teaching or Academic Extension (More than 90 days)

VITEM II

Health Treatment (More than 90 days)

VITEM III

Humanitarian/Refugee (only Haitians)

VITEM IV

Study (More than 90 days)

VITEM V

Work/Technical Assistance or Technology Transfer

VITEM VI

Work in Brazil during Vacation (only New Zealanders and French)

VITEM VII

Religious Activity (More than 90 days)

VITEM VIII

Volunteer Work (More than 90 days)

VITEM IX

Investment

VITEM X

Economic, Scientific, Technological or Cultural Activities

VITEM XI

Family Reunion with a Brazilian Citizen or a Foreign Citizen who is a Temporary or Permanent Resident of Brazil

VITEM XII

Artistic or Sports Activity under contract (More than 90 days)

VITEM XIII

International Agreement

VITEM XIV

Brazilian Immigration Policy

VICAM

Medical Practice Visa for foreign doctors (“More Doctors Program”)

Answer (score 0):

I found this

> Temporary visas - will be
>   applicable for work (with or
>   without an employment
>   contract), research, health
>   treatment, study, vacation or
>   summer job, family reunion,
>   investment etc.
>   Furthermore, one of the
>   important changes introduced
>   by the Law comprehends the
>   possibility of applying for the
>   temporary visa for work by
>   waiving the requirement of a
>   formal job offer and instead
>   providing evidence of a higher
>   degree diploma or equivalent.

Source : https://www.pwc.com/gx/en/services/people-organisation/publications/assets/pwc-brazil-new-migration-law-to-affect-visas-tax-residence-rules.pdf